# Stencil, external libary, require is not defined, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-component, require, stenciljs

I am trying to use [OpenTelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/) library along with Stencil.
After version 0.19 they started to use `require()` for the imports of some internal dependencies.

Stencil does not support require. So app fails on `require is not defined`.

My question is - is it possible to somehow fix the issue and still use the library ?
Can it be fixed by using webpack ?